# Ajax Popup on Select Box Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a ajax popup on list view using JavaScript, check below img :

**Please note that this is LIST VIEW & NOT SELECT BOX**

[image: Img 01]

On click of any product i have used Ajax Pop up which is also working properly, check below image :
[image]

---

Now my major using is that i wanna use SELECT BOX instead of LIST VIEW, so how can i pass a value after selection option from list view and pass it to AJAX MODAL

---

**My CODE :**

```
<ul class="no-js" style="margin: 0px; float: left;">
    <li><b>Product Selection : </b> <a class="clicker" id="select">Add Item...</a>
        <ul style="max-height:200px; overflow:auto;">
            <li id="animation-switcher"><a href="#selectPro" class="proModal" data-id="1~2">Product 01 </a></li>
            <li id="animation-switcher"><a href="#selectPro" class="proModal" data-id="2~2">Product 02</a></li>
            <li id="animation-switcher"><a href="#selectPro" class="proModal" data-id="3~2">Product 03</a></li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

**MY AJAX CODE :**

```
$('a.proModal').click(function(){
                var qid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "phpajaxfile.php", // 
                    data: 'ProSelectid='+qid,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $(".selectForm").html(msg);
                        //$.magnificPopup.close();
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("failure");
                        $.magnificPopup.close();
                    }
                });

            });
```

---

I want to replace ul li with select box and pass the value to ajax file..??

Comment: Okay, but what's your question/problem?

Comment: i want to replace list view by selection box and pass option value to ajax

Comment: hello can u give me plzz popup window codes? plzzzz

Comment: Hello User,

You can google Bootstrap Modal & find the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
<select class="selectprod">
   <option value="1~2"">Product 1</option>
   <option value="2~2">Product 2</option>
   <option value="3~1">Product 3</option>
</select>
```

Your js would be

```
$('.selectprod').on('change',function(){
     var qid = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
     $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "phpajaxfile.php", // 
             data: 'ProSelectid='+qid,
             success: function(msg){
                  $(".selectForm").html(msg);
                  //$.magnificPopup.close();
             },
             error: function(){
                  alert("failure");
                  $.magnificPopup.close();
             }
     });
});
```

You can open modal *[assuming to be bootstrap modal]* with below code!! Place it when you want to call that:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: hello..popup is not opening as in my code i have used anchor link with #selectPro for calling popup..??

Comment: @DhawalMhatre Updated the answer.. check and let me know!!